# How to find and replace end of a line in RStudio

Tags: regex, rstudio

I am working in RStudio and I would like to place a certain string at the end of every selected non-empty line of a .R script.

I tried to use find and replace with regex but I am only able to select the last character of a line (using `.$`) which is not helpful as I do not want to replace this character. I have tried combinations of `\n\r` etc but these return no results.

I am seeking a method either to "carry" the character selected by `.$` into my "replace" string (I don't think this is possible) or to select the new line and express/define a new line in my replace string.

I am neither an rstudio power-user nor a regex wizard so any help or clues are greatly appreciated.

<del>edit: Apologies this may be a moot question. There is an April 2016 mention [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208779498-find-replace-in-Editor) that says the ability to find/replace line endings has not been implemented. Is there a way to check on progress of a feature request?</del>

Comment: Do you really need to replace line endings?  Your question sounds to me like you just want to add something to the end of certain lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following replace all:

**Find:**

```
(.)$
```

**Replace:**

```
\1your_string
```

The quantity `(.)` means to *capture* the last character on a given line, which is then made available in the replacement as `\1`.  Note that empty lines would not match, since they have no characters on them.

Comment: Thanks - this solves my problem in this case and helps me for some other things too.