# How to find and replace with a new line (not a new line character) in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose we have the following in the script pane

```
size = 1, minSize = 0, gridSize = 0, fontFamily = "Segoe UI", 
fontWeight = "bold", color = "random-dark", backgroundColor = "white"
```

And we want to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and find all the `,` - i.e comma followed by a space (technically could also be comma followed by end of line), and replace them with simply a new line (i.e. the equivalent of pressing enter), so we end up with something like

```
size = 1
minSize = 0
gridSize = 0
fontFamily = "Segoe UI" 
fontWeight = "bold"
color = "random-dark"
backgroundColor = "white"
```

How is this done?

Note: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725285/how-to-find-and-replace-end-of-a-line-in-rstudio) (which didn't require replacing with a new line)

Comment: A quickie hack in your specific R script above would be to replace ','s with ';'s. NOT a general solution.

Comment: @JohnGarland thanks John! I figured that out 5 mins after posting this :) It will save a lot of time in the future

Comment: Remember that this is a hack that only works as you have no other commas.

Comment: @JohnGarland the idea I try to implement in my question is also a hack (to replace comma + space), since that combination could too appear in the arguments. But I'm not sure if there is any better solution?

Comment: Just don't use "Replace All". You can then choose yes or no for each one as you go through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go,

1. Do as shown below:

[image]

2. Press "All" button. Done, results as below:

[image]

Comment: Great work! An extra note: in cases where the last `,` on a line is not followed by a space (but is instead followed by a new line), we can use `, |,$` instead of `, ` in the search field (that will look for a comma then space, or a comma then end of line)